# How to purge test sessions in Botium

Tags: testing, automated-tests, chatbot

I'm trying to run Test Set but it looks like it is stucked. All 5 agents are in use and I cannot delete them. Tests fail on ESOCKETTIMEDOUT. I could run same test without problems before.

I tried to click on "Send cancellation request" to Test Session in danger zone to kill it, but I still  can't delete agents (Delete Botium Agent (only possible if not already used)).

[Botium agents pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtVS4.png)

Log from Botium:

```html
2019-05-31T08:31:13.892Z: Job queued for execution
2019-05-31T08:31:13.886Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.378Z botium-box-worker-runtestcases Started processing, JobId #952.

2019-05-31T08:31:14.077Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.382Z botium-BotDriver Loaded Botium configuration file ./botium.json

2019-05-31T08:31:14.143Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.388Z botium-BotDriver BuildCompiler: Capabilites: { PROJECTNAME: 'TM new - Test Session',
  TEMPDIR: 'botiumwork',
  CLEANUPTEMPDIR: true,
  WAITFORBOTTIMEOUT: 10000,
  SIMULATE_WRITING_SPEED: false,
  DOCKERCOMPOSEPATH: 'docker-compose',
  DOCKERMACHINEPATH: 'docker-machine',
  DOCKERMACHINE: false,
  DOCKERIMAGE: 'node:boron',
  DOCKERUNIQUECONTAINERNAMES: false,
  DOCKERSYSLOGPORT_RANGE: '47100-47299',
  BOT_HEALTH_STATUS: 200,
  SLACK_PUBLISHPORT_RANGE: '46100-46299',
  FACEBOOK_PUBLISHPORT_RANGE: '46300-46499',
  FACEBOOK_SEND_DELIVERY_CONFIRMATION: true,
  BOTFRAMEWORK_PUBLISHPORT_RANGE: '46500-46699',
  BOTFRAMEWORK_WEBHOOK_PORT: 3978,
  BOTFRAMEWORK_WEBHOOK_PATH: 'api/messages',
  BOTFRAMEWORK_CHANNEL_ID: 'facebook',
  SIMPLEREST_PING_RETRIES: 6,
  SIMPLEREST_PING_TIMEOUT: 10000,
  SIMPLEREST_PING_VERB: 'GET',
  SIMPLEREST_METHOD: 'GET',
  WEBSPEECH_SERVER_PORT: 46050,
  WEBSPEECH_LANGUAGE: 'en-US',
  WEBSPEECH_CLOSEBROWSER: true,
  SCRIPTING_TXT_EOL: '\n',
  SCRIPTING_XLSX_EOL_SPLIT: '\r',
  SCRIPTING_XLSX_EOL_WRITE: '\r\n',
  SCRIPTING_XLSX_STARTROW: 2,
  SCRIPTING_XLSX_STARTCOL: 1,
  SCRIPTING_NORMALIZE_TEXT: false,
  SCRIPTING_ENABLE_MEMORY: false,
  SCRIPTING_MATCHING_MODE: 'includeLowerCase',
  SCRIPTING_UTTEXPANSION_MODE: 'all',
  SCRIPTING_UTTEXPANSION_RANDOM_COUNT: 1,
  SCRIPTING_MEMORYEXPANSION_KEEP_ORIG: false,
  RETRY_USERSAYS_ONERROR_REGEXP: [],
  RETRY_USERSAYS_NUMRETRIES: 1,
  RETRY_USERSAYS_FACTOR: 1,
  RETRY_USERSAYS_MINTIMEOUT: 1000,
  ASSERTERS:
   [ { ref: 'HASLINK',
       src: 'botium-asserter-basiclink',
       global: false,
       args: null } ],
  LOGIC_HOOKS: [],
  USER_INPUTS: [],
  CONTAINERMODE: 'webdriverio',
  WEBDRIVERIO_URL: 'https://chat.t-mobile.cz/chat/',
  WEBDRIVERIO_PROFILE: '',
  WEBDRIVERIO_INPUT_ELEMENT: '<input />',
  WEBDRIVERIO_INPUT_ELEMENT_VISIBLE_TIMEOUT: 10000,
  WEBDRIVERIO_OUTPUT_ELEMENT:
   "//div[@class='gaid-text-message gaid-text-message--isBot'][position()=last()-1]//p",
  WEBDRIVERIO_IGNOREUPFRONTMESSAGES: false,
  WEBDRIVERIO_USERNAME: '',
  WEBDRIVERIO_PASSWORD: '',
  WEBDRIVERIO_SCREENSHOTS: 'onstop',
  FBPAGERECEIVER_REDISURL: { port: '6379', host: 'redis', db: 0, options: {} },
  WEBDRIVERIO_OPTIONS:
   { desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome', name: 'TM new - Test Session' },
     protocol: 'http',
     host: '192.168.99.100',
     port: '4444',
     path: '/wd/hub' } }

2019-05-31T08:31:14.169Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.393Z botium-ScriptingProvider Using matching mode: includeLowerCase

2019-05-31T08:31:14.214Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.396Z botium-asserterUtils Loaded Default asserter - [ 'BUTTONS',
  'MEDIA',
  'PAUSE_ASSERTER',
  'ENTITIES',
  'ENTITY_VALUES',
  'INTENT',
  'INTENT_CONFIDENCE' ]

2019-05-31T08:31:14.251Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.402Z botium-asserterUtils Loaded Default logic hook - [ 'PAUSE',
  'WAITFORBOT',
  'SET_SCRIPTING_MEMORY',
  'CLEAR_SCRIPTING_MEMORY',
  'INCLUDE' ]

2019-05-31T08:31:14.339Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.403Z botium-asserterUtils Loaded Default user input - [ 'BUTTON', 'MEDIA', 'FORM' ]

2019-05-31T08:31:14.396Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.407Z botium-asserterUtils Trying to load HASLINK asserter from botium-asserter-basiclink

2019-05-31T08:31:14.433Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.410Z botium-asserterUtils Loaded HASLINK SUCCESSFULLY

2019-05-31T08:31:14.470Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.504Z botium-box-worker-runtestcases found 1 convos ...

2019-05-31T08:31:14.512Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.504Z botium-box-worker-runtestcases batchNum: 1 batchCount: 1 convosPerBatch: 1 batchStart: 0 batchEnd: 0 batchLength: 1

2019-05-31T08:31:14.548Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.507Z botium-BotDriver Build - Botium Core Version: 1.4.14

2019-05-31T08:31:14.586Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.510Z botium-BotDriver Build - Capabilites: { PROJECTNAME: 'TM new - Test Session',
  TEMPDIR: 'botiumwork',
  CLEANUPTEMPDIR: true,
  WAITFORBOTTIMEOUT: 10000,
  SIMULATE_WRITING_SPEED: false,
  DOCKERCOMPOSEPATH: 'docker-compose',
  DOCKERMACHINEPATH: 'docker-machine',
  DOCKERMACHINE: false,
  DOCKERIMAGE: 'node:boron',
  DOCKERUNIQUECONTAINERNAMES: false,
  DOCKERSYSLOGPORT_RANGE: '47100-47299',
  BOT_HEALTH_STATUS: 200,
  SLACK_PUBLISHPORT_RANGE: '46100-46299',
  FACEBOOK_PUBLISHPORT_RANGE: '46300-46499',
  FACEBOOK_SEND_DELIVERY_CONFIRMATION: true,
  BOTFRAMEWORK_PUBLISHPORT_RANGE: '46500-46699',
  BOTFRAMEWORK_WEBHOOK_PORT: 3978,
  BOTFRAMEWORK_WEBHOOK_PATH: 'api/messages',
  BOTFRAMEWORK_CHANNEL_ID: 'facebook',
  SIMPLEREST_PING_RETRIES: 6,
  SIMPLEREST_PING_TIMEOUT: 10000,
  SIMPLEREST_PING_VERB: 'GET',
  SIMPLEREST_METHOD: 'GET',
  WEBSPEECH_SERVER_PORT: 46050,
  WEBSPEECH_LANGUAGE: 'en-US',
  WEBSPEECH_CLOSEBROWSER: true,
  SCRIPTING_TXT_EOL: '\n',
  SCRIPTING_XLSX_EOL_SPLIT: '\r',
  SCRIPTING_XLSX_EOL_WRITE: '\r\n',
  SCRIPTING_XLSX_STARTROW: 2,
  SCRIPTING_XLSX_STARTCOL: 1,
  SCRIPTING_NORMALIZE_TEXT: false,
  SCRIPTING_ENABLE_MEMORY: false,
  SCRIPTING_MATCHING_MODE: 'includeLowerCase',
  SCRIPTING_UTTEXPANSION_MODE: 'all',
  SCRIPTING_UTTEXPANSION_RANDOM_COUNT: 1,
  SCRIPTING_MEMORYEXPANSION_KEEP_ORIG: false,
  RETRY_USERSAYS_ONERROR_REGEXP: [],
  RETRY_USERSAYS_NUMRETRIES: 1,
  RETRY_USERSAYS_FACTOR: 1,
  RETRY_USERSAYS_MINTIMEOUT: 1000,
  ASSERTERS:
   [ { ref: 'HASLINK',
       src: 'botium-asserter-basiclink',
       global: false,
       args: null } ],
  LOGIC_HOOKS: [],
  USER_INPUTS: [],
  CONTAINERMODE: 'webdriverio',
  WEBDRIVERIO_URL: 'https://chat.t-mobile.cz/chat/',
  WEBDRIVERIO_PROFILE: '',
  WEBDRIVERIO_INPUT_ELEMENT: '<input />',
  WEBDRIVERIO_INPUT_ELEMENT_VISIBLE_TIMEOUT: 10000,
  WEBDRIVERIO_OUTPUT_ELEMENT:
   "//div[@class='gaid-text-message gaid-text-message--isBot'][position()=last()-1]//p",
  WEBDRIVERIO_IGNOREUPFRONTMESSAGES: false,
  WEBDRIVERIO_USERNAME: '',
  WEBDRIVERIO_PASSWORD: '',
  WEBDRIVERIO_SCREENSHOTS: 'onstop',
  FBPAGERECEIVER_REDISURL: { port: '6379', host: 'redis', db: 0, options: {} },
  WEBDRIVERIO_OPTIONS:
   { desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome', name: 'TM new - Test Session' },
     protocol: 'http',
     host: '192.168.99.100',
     port: '4444',
     path: '/wd/hub' } }

2019-05-31T08:31:14.636Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.519Z botium-BotDriver Build - Sources : { LOCALPATH: '.',
  GITPATH: 'git',
  GITBRANCH: 'master',
  GITDIR: '.' }

2019-05-31T08:31:14.671Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.524Z botium-BotDriver Build - Envs : { IS_BOTIUM_CONTAINER: true }

2019-05-31T08:31:14.704Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.592Z botium-PluginConnectorContainer Invalid Botium plugin loaded from webdriverio, expected PluginVersion, PluginClass fields

2019-05-31T08:31:14.732Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.595Z botium-PluginConnectorContainer Botium plugin botium-connector-webdriverio loaded

2019-05-31T08:31:14.769Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.597Z botium-connector-webdriverio Validate called

2019-05-31T08:31:14.801Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.600Z botium-connector-webdriverio Build called

2019-05-31T08:31:14.837Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:13.603Z botium-connector-webdriverio Start called

2019-05-31T08:31:24.389Z: 2019-05-31T08:31:24.371Z botium-box-worker sending heartbeat ...

2019-05-31T08:36:24.471Z: 2019-05-31T08:36:24.420Z botium-box-worker sending heartbeat ...

2019-05-31T08:37:15.925Z: 2019-05-31T08:37:15.880Z botium-box-worker-runtestcases Test Session Run failed (Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT), doing additional BotDriver Clean.

2019-05-31T08:37:15.961Z: 2019-05-31T08:37:15.881Z botium-connector-webdriverio Clean called

2019-05-31T08:40:02.054Z: 2019-05-31T08:40:02.006Z botium-BaseContainer Cleanup rimrafing temp dir /app/agent/botiumwork/TM-new-Test-Session-20190531-083113-vI4Bx

2019-05-31T08:40:02.357Z: Job failed: Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
```

Selenium hub log:

```html
08:06:36.629 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
08:06:36.849 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$5] - Launching Selenium Grid hub on port 4444
2019-05-31 08:06:37.333:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1175ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
08:06:38.033 INFO [Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
08:06:38.040 INFO [Hub.start] - Nodes should register to http://172.19.0.4:4444/grid/register/
08:06:38.040 INFO [Hub.start] - Clients should connect to http://172.19.0.4:4444/wd/hub
08:06:40.894 INFO [DefaultGridRegistry.add] - Registered a node http://172.19.0.3:5555
08:06:40.907 INFO [DefaultGridRegistry.add] - Registered a node http://172.19.0.2:5555
08:07:47.391 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {browserName: firefox, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, loggingPrefs: org.openqa.selenium.logging..., name: TM new - Test Session, requestOrigins: {name: webdriverio, url: http://webdriver.io, version: 4.14.4}, rotatable: true}
08:07:47.409 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=ad8a2987-e350-456e-b9cf-25ac008d5255, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=firefox, maxInstances=1, moz:firefoxOptions={log={level=info}}, platformName=LINUX, version=67.0, applicationName=, platform=LINUX}
08:13:58.927 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, loggingPrefs: org.openqa.selenium.logging..., name: TM new - Test Session, requestOrigins: {name: webdriverio, url: http://webdriver.io, version: 4.14.4}, rotatable: true}
08:13:58.935 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=3f83f707-e0ad-406f-9081-bc7185515bdf, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=1, platformName=LINUX, version=74.0.3729.169, applicationName=, platform=LINUX}
08:31:13.686 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, loggingPrefs: org.openqa.selenium.logging..., name: TM new - Test Session, requestOrigins: {name: webdriverio, url: http://webdriver.io, version: 4.14.4}, rotatable: true}
08:31:13.697 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=3f83f707-e0ad-406f-9081-bc7185515bdf, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=1, platformName=LINUX, version=74.0.3729.169, applicationName=, platform=LINUX}
08:39:59.952 WARN [RequestHandler.process] - The client is gone for session ext. key b54b779b8d4cb90133cf3386ca7ef664, terminating
08:40:02.245 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {browserName: firefox, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, loggingPrefs: org.openqa.selenium.logging..., name: TM new - Test Session, requestOrigins: {name: webdriverio, url: http://webdriver.io, version: 4.14.4}, rotatable: true}
08:40:02.251 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=ad8a2987-e350-456e-b9cf-25ac008d5255, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=firefox, maxInstances=1, moz:firefoxOptions={log={level=info}}, platformName=LINUX, version=67.0, applicationName=, platform=LINUX}
IP & PORTS
You can access this container using the following IP address and port:

DOCKER PORT ACCESS URL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the agent records in Botium Box doesn't help - this is just how Botium Box keeps tracks of the connected agents, it has no influence on the actual processes.

The logs you attached are not looking bad, it's just that obviously there is a problem when connecting to the Selenium hub. In case the agent processes are really stuck or crashed, you can just restart the docker containers to bring them up again.

Comment: Looks like problems was caused by internal network restrictions - proxy blocking communication between Botium box and Selenium hub docker containers... Thanks for answer.